# Youtube loading with no css

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, css

I am facing a serious issue here. Youtube is loading with no css file in any browser in my laptop. Its completely messed up as  cant load any videos whatsoever, I cleared cache, re-installed chrome,check the host file but no luck. I inspected the page and got these

```
> GET https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-core-webp-vflOXuTs6.css
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):13 GET
> https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/QxvDVqZdqRU/hqdefault.jpg
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):554 GET
> https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/hafj2CLubHE/mqdefault.jpg
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):600 GET
> https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-home-c4-webp-vflIvxUPq.css
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):14 GET
> https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-pageframe-webp-vflgztbLD.css
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):22 GET
> https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-guide-webp-vfl_uF6sZ.css
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):23 GET
> https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/YuFs_aHhm44/mqdefault.jpg
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):648 GET
> https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/SDlTZofXa7c/mqdefault.jpg
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):696 GET
> https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-scheduler-vflKNUgKf.js
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):9 GET
> https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/spf-vflXayUFd.js
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):4263 GET
> https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-en_US-vflHVohGO/base.js
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):4264 Uncaught ReferenceError:
> spf is not defined (index):4265 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a
> function (index):4270 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
> (index):4303 GET https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):31
```

Anyone has any ideas Please help me.

Comment: Yes, tried with all extension disabled as well, but still same

Comment: Have you tried a third-party DNS provider?  Because the errors are pretty clear, you attempt to connect to the host, and it never happens which inidcates your DNS provider is unable to find a route.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there any way to check that, but I dont think I am using any third party dns provider. It was working fine few days back.

Comment: Verify if you are then update the question